# Evaluating a nested data type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that evaluates a nested boolean data type. My issue comes from comparing a data type within a data type. The first two (Lit and Or) compile fine but I don't understand how to incorporate the first type into the function of the SecondExpr. As I type it out, I feel like I'm taking the longest way possible when something shorter works.

Here are the two data types.

```
data Expr = Val Int
          | Add Expr Expr
          | Sub Expr Expr
          | Mul Expr Expr
          | Div Expr Expr
          | If SecondExpr Expr Expr

data SecondExpr = Lit Bool
                | Or SecondExpr SecondExpr 
                | EqualTo Expr Expr
                | LessThan Expr Expr
```

(Another issue I'm having is creating examples of SecondExpr to test because, conceptually, I see every Expr as the 6 different types of Expr. That means, for every Expr Expr there would be hundreds of guards.)

Below is the code so far:

```
eval :: SecondExpr -> Bool
eval (Lit n)                   = n
eval (Or e1 e2)
  | True && True               = True
  | True && False              = True
  | False && True              = True
  | otherwise                  = False
eval (EqualTo e1 e2)
  | (Add e1 e2) == (Add e1 e2) = True
  | (Sub e1 e2) == (Sub e1 e2) = True
  | (Mul e1 e2) == (Mul e1 e2) = True
  | (Div e1 e2) == (Div e1 e2) = True
  | otherwise                  = False
eval (LessThan e1 e2)
  | (Add e1 e2) == (Add e1 e2) = True
  | (Sub e1 e2) == (Sub e1 e2) = True
  | (Mul e1 e2) == (Mul e1 e2) = True
  | (Div e1 e2) == (Div e1 e2) = True
  | otherwise                  = False
```

This is the error I get:

```
    * No instance for (Eq Expr) arising from a use of `=='
    * In the expression: (Add e1 e2) == (Add e1 e2)
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for `eval':
        (Add e1 e2) == (Add e1 e2)
      In an equation for `eval':
          eval (EqualTo e1 e2)
            | (Add e1 e2) == (Add e1 e2) = True
            | (Sub e1 e2) == (Sub e1 e2) = True
            | (Mul e1 e2) == (Mul e1 e2) = True
            | (Div e1 e2) == (Div e1 e2) = True
            | otherwise = False
   |
24 |   | (Add e1 e2)       == (Add e1 e2) = True
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So I know my syntax is wrong but how do you substitute an Expression within the function of an Expression?

Comment: `True && True` is the same as just `True`. A guard expression of `| True` always succeeds; it's like having no guard at all: `eval (Or e1 e2) = True`.

Comment: I'm unclear what `SecondExpr` is for. You probably want eg. `eval (Or e1 e2) = eval e1 || eval e2` rather than what you've written, which is constant `True`. For `EqualTo`, you'll need an `eval'` on `Expr` to some equatable type, then just `eval (EqualTo e1 e2) = eval' e1 == eval' e2` (and you can see how to easily adapt that for `LessThan`). This also solves the issue of combinatorial explosion you observed, though as I said the overall design seems questionable but hard to be more helpful without more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need two evaluation functions:

```
evalNum :: Expr -> Int
```

and

```
evalBool :: SecondExpr -> Bool
```

Neither of them should use any guards (`| ...`).

For example, `evalBool` would look like this:

```
evalBool (Lit n) = n
evalBool (Or e1 e2) = evalBool e1 || evalBool e2
evalBool (EqualTo e1 e2) = evalNum e1 == evalNum e2
evalBool (LessThan e1 e2) = evalNum e1 < evalNum e2
```

Subexpressions are evaluated recursively with their corresponding `eval` functions, and the results are combined using appropriate Haskell operators (such as `||`, `==`, `<`).

Implementing `evalNum` is left as an exercise for the reader.